# Embed a web browser in a Python program

Tags: python, linux, browser

How can I embed a web browser in a Python program? It needs to run on Linux (GTK, Qt are fine), or cross-platform.

I have looked at embedding pywebgtk and [Qt's WebKit widget](http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Languages/Python/PyKDE_WebKit_Tutorial). But these seem to have little more than a rendering engine. In particular, I'd like support for back/forward and tabbed browsing. Is something like this pre-packaged, or do I have to implement it myself?

[wxWebConnect](http://www.kirix.com/labs/wxwebconnect.html) seems to be roughly what I was thinking of, but it has no Python bindings.

Comment: See https://kmandla.wordpress.com/2010/05/24/the-1-2kb-python-browser-script/ and the comments; read http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebBrowserProgramming especially the section on "Python Wrappers around Web "Libraries" and Browser Technology"

Comment: My knee-jerk response is that you are either developing a web application and you use a browser or you're not and you don't use a browser.  A hybrid solution seems a bit sticky.

Comment: @agf: If I'm reading those right, both links only deal with embedding a just a WebKit renderer, which I already know how to do, rather than an actual browser.

Comment: I think the links in the comments to the blog post talk about actual minimal browsers built around webkit in Python.

Comment: @agf: I'd prefer to embed a well-developed browser rather than implement tabs etc. and work out all the glitches myself. I'd just launch the default browser, except it's inconvenient for the user to separately open and close the web server and the UI, when they're conceptually one application.

Comment: If you need a full browser, rather than a rendering engine, have you considered simply starting a second instance of a browser?

Comment: @Mechanical snail - given your last reply to agf, it sounds like you're trying to get a browser and a server app to start and stop together. Why not just write a small application to start them both, monitor them and stop when one is terminated?

Comment: @jdigital: I've considered it, but I don't see how. `firefox` returns immediately, so you can't tell when the user exited the browser. `chromium-browser` doesn't seem to support separate profiles (even if you specify `--user-data-dir=/tmp/somedir`, the saved passwords from the default profile show up!)

Comment: There is surely a way to determine when a process terminates.  If you can't find the answer, try posting a new question.

Comment: `firefox` is now starting synchronously, so I'll use that. (I'm not sure what changed.)  I'll leave the question up since it's could be useful outside of my particular purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium/2.7.0

You can install the selenium package and run a server (same machine, just a different process) with it which you connect to with your python code:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.7.0.jar
```

then:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

browser = webdriver.Firefox() # Get local session of firefox
browser.get("http://www.yahoo.com") # Load page
assert "Yahoo!" in browser.title
elem = browser.find_element_by_name("p") # Find the query box
elem.send_keys("seleniumhq" + Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(0.2) # Let the page load, will be added to the API
try:
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'http://seleniumhq.org')]")
except NoSuchElementException:
    assert 0, "can't find seleniumhq"
browser.close()
```

You could use `subprocess` to start the server inside your python code.